# Inter-classloader communication in the same JVM

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I have a JVM library (call it "`tool`") which provides a service. For some specific features, `tool` has to call third-party code. It does that by loading a user-defined Jar file into a custom classloader and invoking a user-defined function accepting a list of `String`s as arguments. Essentially, it's a basic plugin infrastructure.

For my use case, I would like to make two plugins talk to each other within these constraints. The plugins can do anything they want (including spawning long-lived background threads), but they only get called by `tool`.

The simplest solution which wouldn't work for me is to "merge" both plugins together. (Assume that the scenario above is a given. I've wildly simplified things.)

My current solution would be to change both plugins to open TCP sockets and make `tool` pass the port number upon initialization. However, that feels like a terrible hack, because they already run in the same process and networking would needlessly complicate matters.

My question is: Is there any painless inter-classloader communication library for the JVM? It just needs to support passing strings and native types (arrays, ...), but crucially, it must be initializable using only strings. Then, it would be possible for me to package it up for `tool` and let the other plugins communicate through it. Assume that I can add arbitrary dependencies to the plugins, but not to `tool`.

Comment: It just occurred to me that my scenario would be similar to making two web applications talk to each other in an application server (but without any support from the server).

Comment: not an answer, and primarily opinion based, but osgi is a way to build such application. more easily, just share some classes between the classloaders

Comment: @JérémieB And even if you choose not to use OSGI (why would you do that?) the principle of all sensible solutions is the same: rely on classes loaded by a shared classloader, if push comes to shove, you can even pass JSON messages in a `String`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the way `tool` loads the plugins. Especially, I can't specify common classes.

Comment: Maybe I haven't understood the question, but it seems like the constraints you are stating are mutually incompatible. You need to change the application to communicate between plugins; however you can't change the application?

Comment: I need to change the _plugins_ to communicate, without any help from the framework.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to make the "communication layer" part of the framework (i.e. in the the base classloader).

if you have a fairly specific need, it might be pretty easy to make a relatively specific api.  one plugin registers as a provider and the other plugins can be consumers.

if your needs are broader than that, then you might want to implement (or find) some sort of "message bus" type infrastructure.  something that provides a lightweight mechanism for passing "messages" dynamically.  each plugin can use specific names as message destinations, and then other plugins can send messages to them (and presumably receive replies).

yet another possibility which is built into every jdk is JMX (an oft overlooked yet powerful technology).  you can provide strongly typed apis using the core types and any code running on the jvm can interact with those apis (double bonus is that you can interact with them *outside* the jvm as well).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change `tool`. Can you give me some pointers on JMX for communication/message passing?

Comment: @larsrh - there are lots of jmx tutorials online.  i'd focus on MXBeans, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/mxbeans.html .  as a side note, jmx allows you to use true APIs as opposed to a strictly message passing style interaction.

Comment: @larsrh - also the javadoc itself is pretty extensive: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/package-summary.html#package_description and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/MXBean.html

Comment: If you can’t change `tool`, you can still implement a communication architecture as a plugin that loads the other plugins by itself. Since you already thought about merging them into one plugin, having a modular plugin is much cleaner…

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar(ish) situation, and I was able to make something work using reflection.

I had a class A, which was loaded using a custom classloader (beyond my control). It wanted to interact with another class, B, which was only loaded using the system classloader, `AppClassLoader`. To 'see' them, A had to explicitly use that classloader and create an instance via reflection.

```
    ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        // Switch classloaders to the system classloader, rather than the transformer classloader we were loaded with
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = cl.loadClass("com.example.B");
            Object b = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Things got even messier when I wanted to have B invoke something on A. B had no way at all of getting A's classloader. I inverted the control, and just passed A's data, D, to B so that B could do the work. D's class was also loaded with the A classloader. A had to use reflection to invoke the method on B, and the method signature had to only have JVM core libraries in it, or A could not find the method by reflection.

```
someMethod(D data[loaded by A-classloader]) != someMethod(D data[loaded by B-classloader])
```

so the method had to be

```
someMethod(Object data)
```

and B could not cast `data` to `D` because the classloaders were different. It also could not use reflection to invoke methods on `data` if the signature involved 'interesting' classes that are loaded by one of the application classloaders.

I created a D-wrapper, W. W had a method signature simple enough to be found by reflection even from a different classloader, `doSomething(String s)`. B could invoke `doSomething` on W, and W could then invoke the methods with non-JVM-library types. This is ugly, but it works.

Alternatively, if a wrapper can't do complex enough operations, serialization would also allow passing actual object instances back and forth between classloaders. It's not great, but it might be cleaner and less hacky than all of the reflection.